# Как сохранить и отобразить форму, после обновления страницы

Tags: django

Я хочу после вписания даных отобразить их, то есть сохранить и отобразить в форме ниже

Моя форма или же forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Zadanie

class ZadanieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Zadanie
        fields = "__all__"
```

views

```
import django_filters
def home_page(request):
    form = ZadanieForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ZadanieForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("valid", form)
    return render(request, "newapp/home_page.html", {'zform': ZadanieForm()})
```

главное с файла html

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in zform %}
            <div>{{ field.label_tag}} {{ field }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-success px-5 py-3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <table id="zadanieTable" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {% for field in zform %}
          <th scope="col">{{ field.label_tag}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передайте только что созданный объект

```
...
instance = None
if .....:
    form = ZadanieForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
    ....
return render(request, "newapp/home_page.html", {'zform': ZadanieForm(instance=instance)})
```

Но лучше, после создания отправлять пользователя на страницу редактирования этого объекта. Так вы сможете менять объект сколько угодно раз и выводить его.

```
# views.py

def home_page(...):
    ...
    if fors.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        return redirect('zadanie_edit_url', kwargs=dict(pk=instance.pk))
    ...

def zadanie_edit(request, *args, **kwargs):
    z = Zadanie.objects.get(kwargs['pk'])
    form = ZadanieForm(instance=z)
    return render(request, context=dict(zform=form), temlate_name="....")


#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('zadanie-<pk:int>/', zadanie_edit, name='zadanie_edit_url'),
]
```